# serialization "this" dosen't work

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I want to serialize this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SCMng
{

[XmlElement("SC")]
public ObservableCollection<SC> SCCollection { get; set; }

[XmlIgnore]
public SC SCPreview { get; set; }

public SCMng()
{
   this.SCCollection = new ObservableCollection<SC>();
   this.SCPreview = new SC();
}

public void SaveMD(string pPath)
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(pPath));

   if (System.IO.File.Exists(pPath))
       System.IO.File.Delete(pPath);

   var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SCMng));
   using (var fs = new FileStream(pPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
      ser.Serialize(fs, this);
}

}
```

Inside my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I wrote this:

```
SCMng fooBar = new SCMng();

public void Save(){
    this.fooBar.SaveMD(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\new.xml");
}
```

Where is my mistake? I get no exception but the save method doesn't create the file. With the line `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(pPath));` I get an `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Maybe someone of you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you step through your code with the debugger? obviously the file cannot be found. Anyway we can´t know where it should be located and where it *actually* is.

Comment: I think you are trying to create a directory in another directory which doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe the process does not have the habilitations to write on that folder. (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.baseDirectory)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I was searching the problem for 2-3 hours now... I had a copy of my project and I was looking into the wrong one... Time to downvote my question. Anyways thanks!